# Getting Warning: SCM Credentials on Azure WebApp deployment

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line-interface, devops

We are migrating from Jenkins to Azure and in our deployment we used Powershell scripts, for our initial move we are trying not to adjust our Powershell scripts and just change the bare minimum to get them working.

On the running of command:

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --name Name --resource-group RG --src Path/To/Zip.zip
```

When we used this command before we got the warning:

> WARNING: Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment

We now get this warning as an Error:

> [error]WARNING: Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment

I have adjust the settings to try continue past errors but it falls out anyway. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please check Azure CLI version. If you use azure cli to deploy, its version must be 2.0.21 or later. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip

Comment: Ah sorry should have added more information, we are using the Agent Job "Azure Powershell Script" and then calling the file from our repo, I am running it with the option "Latest installed version"

Comment: Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: That looks like an information message on my system. I'd say whatever is reporting that as a WARNING is interpreting the message incorrectly. This is normal behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I am using version 2.0.60 of Azure-cli. I have tried with `az webapp deployment source config-zip` command, I also got the warning. But the webapp was deployed successfully.

[image]

You can also [deploy the zip file via browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#deploy-zip-file).

1.In the browser, navigate to `https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeployUI`.

2.Drag the zip file to the file explorer area on the web page